# MOLUSCE plugin issue for QGIS 3.12.1

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, molusce

I try to use [MOLUSCE plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/molusce/) (versions 3.0.13, 3.0.11, 3.0.10, and 3.0.9) in QGIS 3.12.1, none of them are functioning.

Your suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: Is there any alternate plugin else to be used instead of MOLUSCE compatible with this Qqgis?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing instantly pops up in my mind. But you can check these articles [Free LandUse/LandCover change models/software for rural areas ?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Free_LandUse_LandCover_change_models_software_for_rural_areas) and [I looking for some software or tool to make simulation of cellular automata in land use change?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/I_looking_for_some_software_or_tool_to_make_simulation_of_cellular_automata_in_land_use_change)

Comment: @Taras I forgot that I answered the same question two year ago. :)

Comment: No worries, the answer did not change within two years =) I think it is a common GIS SE problem/issue, I am adamant that often a question was previously been answered (at least partially).

Answer (score 1):

The [MOLUSCE plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/molusce/) was not updated to be compatible with QGIS 3. The last update was conducted in March 24, 2017 which was before the release of QGIS 3 in 23 February 2018. Check the version release date in the above link of the plugin. Here is the history of QGIS release date from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS).